# Program unresponsive after cin >>

Tags: c++

I'm testing operator overloading and it seems to be getting hung up with the overloaded '>>' operator. I input the numbers and hit enter and then the cursor just sits on the next line winking at me.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

#include "OpTesting.h"

int main() {

    Testing tObject(8);
    Testing tObject2;

    cout<<"\nEnter 7 numbers" <<endl;
    cout<<":: ";
    cin>>tObject;

    cout<<"\nFirst object contents: ";
    cout<<tObject;

    cout<<"\nAssigning contents of first object to second object" <<endl;
    tObject = tObject2;

    cout<<"\nContents of second object: ";
    cout<<tObject2;

    return 0;
}
```

**function definitions**

```
Testing::Testing(int arraySize) : length(arraySize) {

    cout<<"Object initialized" <<endl;
    ptr = new int[length];

    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        ptr[x] = 0;
    }

}
Testing::Testing(const Testing &toBeCopied) {

    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        ptr[x] = toBeCopied.ptr[x];
    }
}

Testing::~Testing() {

    delete[] ptr;

}

const Testing &Testing::operator=(const Testing &toBeAssigned) {

    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        ptr[x] = toBeAssigned.ptr[x];
    }

    return toBeAssigned;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Testing &data) {

    for(int x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        output <<data.ptr[x];
        if(x == data.length) {
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

    return output;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &input, Testing &data) {

    for(int x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        input >> data.ptr[x];
    }

    return input;
}
```

I tried searching this site for a solution but none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: `cin` don't know about `Testing` class, so you need to overload `<<` operator.

Comment: I did overload the << operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Testing tObject(8);
...
cout<<"\nEnter 7 numbers" <<endl;
cout<<":: ";
cin>>tObject;
```

This seems like it will try to parse 8 numbers, not 7. Did you try entering 8 numbers?

Also regarding "*I input the numbers and hit enter*", separating individual numbers with space and enter will be the same, which can be confusing.

---

Additionally, this conditional statement will never run, `x` will be at most `data.length - 1`:

```
    if(x == data.length) {
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

---

Moreover, the copy constructor does not set `length` and `ptr` correctly and the `operator=` does not either and should rather `return *this`, ...

Comment: That did it, frustratingly it seems that those times that I finally give up and ask for help it's usually something so ridiculous as this.Embarrassingly enough I did not add spaces between the numbers. Thanks for your help, on both issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
Testing tObject(8);
cout<<"\nEnter 7 numbers" <<endl;
cin>>tObject;
```

You create `tObject` with length 8, then you prompt for 7 numbers.  I would guess you enter 7 numbers, so its sitting waiting for the 8th number...